# Python calling class variable in forloop

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python, and I have confused with the below for loop usage. Can anyone please help me to understand the class usage in the below forloop.

```
import sys

def checkline():
    glb.linecount += 1
    w = glb.l.split()
    glb.wordcount += len(w)

class glb:
    linecount = 0
    wordcount = 0
    l = []


f = open('Untitled9.ipynb','r')

for glb.l in f.readlines(): #what glb.l exactly does?
    checkline()
print(glb.linecount, glb.wordcount)
```

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements, section starting *"If the target is an attribute reference:"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This entire program counts the lines and words in a file. specifically,
`glb.l` becomes each line in a file, so you could iterate and count the words in each one of them.
 Let me pseudo code it for you.

```
Open the file `Untitled9.ipynb` for reading. //f
For each line in the file: // checkline
    Store the line.// youre adding the line to glb.l, which you will later iterate on to count the words in the file.
    Add one to the line count.
    For each space, add one to the word count. // counting the results of the split() on glb.l
Print the line and the word count.
```

Comment: Thank you and that is clear, there is no method to split the list items, how its getting split .

Comment: @SrikanthBhandary Reread your code - there actually is. Between the words, `w = glb.l.split()` seperates, and between the line, each line is called as an iteration of the loop, which seperates them. Glad I helped :)

Comment: @Abramov, I got to know, I confused because I have declared "l" as a list and its type gets changed in the for loop. Thanks